# SP 2013 Online Can I make a Persistent Link to Document or link to Download document column in Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Neither of the suggested solutions work for me. I don't have access to SP Designer. I have no clue how to use Powershel. I don't I have a library called **Statements**. My Site URL is `https://exploder.sharepoint.com/1e1g/Statements`.
I am sharing a document library with some other people and would like to allow them the ability to download the documents. I know the 'FileLeafRef' Name field allows this, but it's a huge task to rename each document. This would be a massive help.

Comment: What is the problem? The fact you've shared a document library and have poorly named files people don't know what they are downloading? By clicking on the Name or the ... menu, they can download the file.

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding. That's the problem -- I'd like the naming conventions to appear uniform. I have created a calculated column that gives them a name based on their content type. The issue is that the 'Type' Icon (linked to document) ins't linked to the document. I need a way to allow them to download the document from a page view (with the document library as a Web Part). Does that make sense?